# c9.io mystyle.css not connecting on any workspace

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am new to programming and the c9 IDE, but looking at the console using developer tools, it says that there is a syntax error and no element found constantly. I did not switch up any code other than the HTML files and one CSS file I wrote. How can I get the CSS to be read? And in the HTML files, it is linked (this all worked yesterday).

Comment: Can you give us more information, like a few lines around where the syntax error is occurring?

Comment: {
    "ace": {
        "@guessTabSize": "true",
        "@newLineMode": "unix",
        "@tabSize": "4",
        "@useSoftTabs": "true"
    } build": {
        "@builder": "auto",
        "@path": "/.c9/builders",
        "@saveall": true
    },
    "find.nak": {
        "@searchLimit": 100
    },
    "general": {
        "@stripws": false},
    "language": {
        "@eslintrc": "true",
        "@instanceHighlight": "true",
        "@semi": "true",
        "@undeclaredVars": "true",
        "@unusedFunctionArgs": "false",
        "@warnLevel": "info"
    },

Comment: "run": {
        "@path": "/.c9/runners",
        "configs": {
            "@inited": "true",
            "json()": {}
        }
    },
    "share": {
        "@app": false,
        "@preview": false,
        "@useOwnerSettings": false
    }
}

Comment: <title>VFS connection does not exist</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/error_handler/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="errorUnknown light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Client Closed Request</h1>
      <h2><em>499 - vfs</em> VFS connection does not exist</h2>

Comment: Is this a problem with the IDE rather than your code? What browser are you using? Have you tried forcing a refresh of the cache? Pressing Ctrl+F5 will usually do that, otherwise you can try closing the browser and then opening it again.

Comment: I have tried using both chrome and firefox. The same issues on both. I think it is the IDE because my code is really basic. I tried the reset and still the same.

Comment: Sounds like it, I'm trying to open an old workspace and I just get a standard browser error page - I'm using IE so it could mean anything!

Comment: Are you viewing your web page on a different tab, or within the preview pane of the IDE? If it's in the preview pane, please open it in a separate tab and take a screenshot of the error along with the page.

Comment: I received a response from Brady at c9: Hi there,

Thanks for reaching out about this and sorry for the issues here. It seems this is something that happens from time to time and it usually resolves itself but any further info you have on it can help us look into solving it for good. For now, it looks like it's back but you can use the file revision history to recover files. Let me know if you have any other info or questions and I'd be happy to help out.

Thanks,
Brady
Cloud9 IDE

Comment: So I guess it was some sort of bug? Also, this happened during the time AWS was acting up, and I am guessing that c9 runs off of them.  Don't know if anyone else noticed lag or craziness with other sites. (I never even knew about these kinds of issues until yesterday.) Thank you so very much @Eraph for trying to help. And Mutahhir17, I will see you on c9. Thanks guys.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed itself!